# Troubleshooting high CPU activity in the WindowServer process

Tags: macos, cpu

As far as I know *WindowServer* process is used by all apps to draw windows that we see. And a lot of people are reporting a problem when their *WindowServer* is using a lot of CPU. Is there any way to find out what process is interacting with *WindowServer* besides looking at the precesses at the *ActivityMonitor*, shutting them down and looking at the result?

Comment: I was suffering from the same issue on my 2014 MacBook after upgrading to Big Sur (from High Sierra, upgraded from Mavericks over the years). I finally got fed up with it and decided to do a clean install, wiping everything and restoring just what I need from backup. Aside from clearing out all the cruft that accumulated on my SSD, the WindowServer issue is gone. Recommended, if you can spare the time for a clean install!

Comment: Update: while my MacBook does feel more responsive and the battery lasts longer since the clean install, WindowServer CPU usage still jumps to 25% when just moving the mouse pointer. Based on the number of reports I've found, I believe this is a bug in Big Sur.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the man page for perfdiagnose. This tool is purpose-made for diagnosing exactly this sort of issue, where a simpler tool like Activity Monitor can only show you symptoms.

The output from perfdiagnose is not intended for end-users, but for developers and teams at Apple. If you're not able to make any sense of the logs it produces, your best bet is to attach them to a [bug report submitted to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Awesome, I think it's just the thing I'm looking for. I'm kinda developer myself. Thank you

Comment: `perfdiagnose` does not appear in my path and there aren't any man pages on it (Mojave 10.14.6 (18G87)). Has it changed it's name? Is it somewhere NOT on the path?

Comment: Now you need to do `sudo sysdiagnose`